# Como utilizar uma palavra-chave do Python como parâmetro?

Tags: python, xml

Como posso passar um parâmetro denominado `from`? O objeto `ET.Element` permite eu passar vários parâmetros que serão atributos do meu elemento no XML, mas como utilizar um nome que é uma palavra-chave da linguagem, como o `from`? Ao fazer `from="A"` dá erro de sintaxe.

```
root = ET.Element("root")

root.append(ET.Element('vType',id="F21a-17-00", color="0,0,255", begin="0" ,end= "900" ,period="900" ,type="automovel", departLane = "random" , from="A" ,to="b"))

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

Dá o erro:

> **SyntaxError**: invalid syntax

Comment: Espero que com a edição reverta essa votação na pergunta. Sinceramente não entendi porque ela *merecia* tantos votos negativos.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode definir um dicionário com os valores desejados:

```
extra = {
    ...
    "from": "A",
    "to": "B"
}
```

E passá-los como parâmetro fazendo a desconstrução do dicionário:

```
element = ET.Element('vType', **extra)
```

Assim você não estará utilizando a *keyword* como nome do objeto.